# Split a text file so that each line does not exceed 50 characters

Tags: regex, vb.net, text, split, lines

I am reading a text file with mostly alpha characters. the content is not really relevant but the size of each line is very important. The process I will feed this text to will require each line be no more than 50 characters. So I will pre-process the text and add line feeds to make sure that happens.

I tried several VB.NET regex like ^.*$ but that doesn't really break up the lines by 50 characters. I would take the result and iterate through each match and then cut it up and write it to an object in memory. Can this be done with a single regex pass?

Otherwise I will use a streamreader and on each line check the length and if <=50 write it out with a streamwriter. if >50 cut it up in sections of 50 and then use streamwriter.

A brief example of my text:

```
 119  SMITH KATY AAAA  F   ZZZ     X NB SX ET
          MILES,200/LM450                       
 120  JONES  THOMAS      W   QQQ  66-W NB OS SC LW EP       
                                              ET
          L/G/B/MAY20-2010/JONES/THOMAS/KEITH      121  BUBBA BILLY  HH4  S   XQT 2PA-F  1 IP SC LH ET
                                              DOCC
 122  NEWTON   IAASAC      S   FTY 240-U NB QC LF KD EE
```

Just looking for tips on how to efficiently do this.

Update: I ended up using the streamreader approach as suggested by SSS. However, I tried to avoid the old Mid function and stick with Substring. Thus i had to make some checks and use some code from another SO post but cant remember which one. anyway here it is:

```
    Dim reader As New StringReader(aSource)
    Dim line As String = Nothing
    Dim writer As New StringWriter
    Dim chunkSize As Integer = 50
    Dim chunk As String

    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine()
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
            Debug.WriteLine(line.Length & "-->" & line)
            'if line length is less than or equal to chunk size then write it out, otherwise cut it up and then write the chunks out
            If line.Length <= chunkSize Then
                writer.WriteLine(line)
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("---------------------")
                For i = 0 To line.Length Step chunkSize
                    Debug.WriteLine("i  =" & i)
                    Debug.WriteLine("i+c=" & i + chunkSize)
                    Debug.WriteLine("L  =" & line.Length)
                    If i + chunkSize > line.Length Then
                        chunk = line.Substring(i, line.Length - i)
                    Else
                        chunk = line.Substring(i, chunkSize)
                    End If
                    Debug.WriteLine("  " & chunk.Length & "-->" & chunk)
                    writer.WriteLine(chunk)
                Next i
                Debug.WriteLine("---------------------")
            End If
        End If
    Loop While (line IsNot Nothing)
    reader.Close()
    reader.Dispose()

    'this cut string now becomes our source
    Debug.WriteLine("==>" & writer.ToString)
    sourceText = writer.ToString

    writer.Close()
    writer.Dispose()
```

Hope that helps someone with the same problem.

Comment: yes I'm absolutely positive. the system that this will go into requires each line to be no more than 50 chars regardless if it wraps over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strFilenameIn As String = "C:\Junk\Input.TXT"
    Dim strFilenameOut As String = "C:\Junk\Output.TXT"
    Try
      Using sr As New StreamReader(strFilenameIn)
        Using sw As New StreamWriter(strFilenameOut)
          Do
            Dim strLine As String = sr.ReadLine()
            If strLine Is Nothing Then Exit Do 'EOF
            For i As Integer = 1 To strLine.Length Step 50
              sw.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, i, 50))
            Next i
          Loop
        End Using
      End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(ex.Message)
      Exit Sub
    End Try
    MsgBox(strfilenameout & " written")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: thanks. i have a variation of this so I think Im on the right path. once i tweak it some more ill post my routine.